# Vectorizing Outer Loop of euclidean distance using numpy on multi-dimensional data

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a 2D matrix of values. Each row is a data point.

```
data = np.array(
   [[2, 2, 3],
    [4, 2, 4],
    [1, 1, 4]])
```

Now if my test point is a single 1D numpy array like:

```
test = np.array([2,3,3])
```

I can do something simple like `np.sqrt(np.sum((test-data)**2,axis=1))` to calculate the distance of the test point relative to all three data points.

However, if test is itself a 2D array of points to be tested, the above doesn't work and I been using something like:

```
test = np.array([[2,3,3],[4,1,2]])    
for i in range(len(test)):
    print np.sqrt(np.sum((test[i]-data)**2,axis=1))

>>> [ 1.          2.44948974  2.44948974]
    [ 2.44948974  2.23606798  3.60555128]
```

In order to calculate each point in my Test set against all the points in the Data set. It seems like there should be a way to vectorize this whole operation so that I get a (2,3) matrix of corresponding distances back without the outer FOR loop

(Note: While this particular example is about Euclidean Distance, I find myself with similar type operations where I would like to perform an operation on all elements of one matrix with the individual elements of another matrix, so I'm hoping there's a generalized way to set up problems of this nature using Numpy.)

Comment: This seems to work, but I'm concerned about memory usage on larger data sets as it seems to require duplicating each test point N times where N is the number of data points to begin with. Thus if there are a 1000 data points, I need to build a 2000 point matrix to test two values.

`print np.reshape(np.sqrt(np.sum((np.reshape(np.repeat(test, len(data), axis=0), (len(test) * len(data), Xdims)) - 
                                 ml.repmat(data, 2, 1)) ** 2, axis=1)), 
                 (2, len(data))).T`

Comment: Just use [scipy's cdist](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.15.1/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.cdist.html) : `from scipy.spatial.distance import cdist ; out = cdist(test,data)`. It's super efficient.

Answer (score 2):

use  [broadcasting](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.10.1/user/basics.broadcasting.html) to do that :

```
from numpy.linalg import norm
norm(data-test[:,None],axis=2)
```

for

```
[ 1.          2.44948974  2.44948974]
[ 2.44948974  2.23606798  3.60555128]
```

Some explanations. It is easier to understand with different shapes, four and two points for exemple:

```
ens1 = np.array(
   [[2, 2, 3],
    [4, 2, 4],
    [1, 1, 4],
    [2, 4, 5]])


ens2 = np.array([[2,3,3],
                 [4,1,2]])  


In [16]: ens1.shape
Out[16]: (4, 3)

In [17]: ens2.shape
Out[17]: (2, 3)
```

Then :

```
In [21]: ens2[:,None].shape 
Out[21]: (2, 1, 3)
```

add a new dimension. now we can  make the 2X4= 8 subtractions :

```
In [22]: (ens1-ens2[:,None]).shape
Out[22]: (2, 4, 3)
```

and take the norm along last axis, for 8 distances :

```
In [23]: norm(ens1-ens2[:,None],axis=2)
Out[23]: 
array([[ 1.        ,  2.44948974,  2.44948974,  2.23606798],
       [ 2.44948974,  2.23606798,  3.60555128,  4.69041576]])
```

Answer (score 1):

What about `np.meshgrid`?

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array(
   [[2, 2, 3],
    [4, 2, 4],
    [1, 1, 4]])


test = np.array([[2,3,3],
                 [4,1,2]])   


d = np.arange(0,3)
t = np.arange(0,2)
d, t = np.meshgrid(d, t)

# print test[t]
# print data[d]
print np.sqrt(np.sum((test[t]-data[d])**2,axis=2))
```

output:

```
[[ 1.          2.44948974  2.44948974]
 [ 2.44948974  2.23606798  3.60555128]]
```

Comment: After seeing Divakar's post, I'd go with `scipy` `cdist`.

Answer (score -2):

You could use a list comprehension:

```
result = np.array([np.sqrt(np.sum((t - data)**2, axis=1)) for t in test])
```

Comment: My understanding is that a comprehension is just a fancy FOR loop. My hope is to exploit the speed of numpy and avoid a loop in Python.