# np.bincount for 1 line, vectorized multidimensional averaging

Tags: python, arrays, matlab, numpy, cython

I am trying to vectorize an operation using numpy, which I use in a python script that I have profiled, and found this operation to be the bottleneck and so needs to be optimized since I will run it many times.

The operation is on a data set of two parts. First, a large set (`n`) of 1D vectors of different lengths (with maximum length, `Lmax`) whose elements are integers from 1 to `maxvalue`. The set of vectors is arranged in a 2D array, `data`, of size `(num_samples,Lmax)` with trailing elements in each row zeroed. The second part is a set of scalar floats, one associated with each vector, that I have a computed and which depend on its length and the integer-value at each position. The set of scalars is made into a 1D array, `Y`, of size `num_samples`.

The desired operation is to **form the average of `Y` over the `n` samples, as a function of** `(value,position along length,length)`.

This entire operation can be vectorized in matlab with use of the `accumarray` function: by using 3 2D arrays of the same size as `data`, whose elements are the corresponding value, position, and length indices of the desired final array:

```
sz_Y = num_samples;
sz_len = Lmax 
sz_pos = Lmax 
sz_val = maxvalue
ind_len = repmat( 1:sz_len      ,1         ,sz_samples);
ind_pos = repmat( 1:sz_pos      ,sz_samples,1         );
ind_val = data
ind_Y   = repmat((1:sz_Y)',1         ,Lmax      );
copiedY=Y(ind_Y);
mask = data>0; 
finalarr=accumarray({ind_val(mask),ind_pos(mask),ind_len(mask)},copiedY(mask), [sz_val sz_pos sz_len])/sz_val;
```

I was hoping to emulate this implementation with `np.bincounts`. However, `np.bincounts` differs to `accumarray` in two relevant ways:

  both arguments must be of same 1D size, and

  there is no option to choose the shape of the output array.

In the above usage of `accumarray`, the list of indices, `{ind_val(mask),ind_pos(mask),ind_len(mask)}`, is 1D cell array of 1x3 arrays used as index tuples, while in `np.bincounts` it must be 1D scalars as far as I understand. I expect `np.ravel` may be useful but am not sure how to use it here to do what I want. I am coming to python from matlab and some things do not translate directly, e.g. the colon operator which ravels in opposite order to ravel. So my question is **how might I use `np.bincount` or any other numpy method to achieve an efficient python implementation of this operation**.

**EDIT:** To avoid wasting time: for these multiD index problems with complicated index manipulation, is the recommend route to just use cython to implement the loops explicity?

**EDIT2:** Alternative Python implementation I just came up with.
Here is a heavy ram solution:

First precalculate:
Using index units for length (i.e., length 1 =0) make a 4D bool array, size `(num_samples,Lmax+1,Lmax+1,maxvalue)` , holding where the conditions are satisfied for each value in `Y`.

```
ALLcond=np.zeros((num_samples,Lmax+1,Lmax+1,maxvalue+1),dtype='bool')
for l in range(Lmax+1):
    for i in range(Lmax+1):
        for v in range(maxvalue+!):
            ALLcond[:,l,i,v]=(data[:,i]==v) & (Lvec==l)`
```

Where `Lvec=[len(row) for row in data]`. Then get the indices for these using `np.where` and initialize a 4D float array into which you will assign the values of Y:

```
[indY,ind_len,ind_pos,ind_val]=np.where(ALLcond)
Yval=np.zeros(np.shape(ALLcond),dtype='float')
```

Now in the loop in which I have to perform the operation, I compute it with the two lines:

```
Yval[ind_Y,ind_len,ind_pos,ind_val]=Y[ind_Y]
Y_avg=sum(Yval)/num_samples
```

This gives a factor of 4 or so speed up over the direct loop implementation. I was expecting more. Perhaps, this is a more tangible implementation for Python heads to digest. Any faster suggestions are welcome :)

Comment: Look at `meshgrid`which helps generate such 2D arrays, a simple example being here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36300023/vectorizing-outer-loop-of-euclidean-distance-using-numpy-on-multi-dimensional-da/36300397#36300397   `numpy` operations over these 2D arrays are automatically `vectorized`(no loops).

Comment: Exactly what I was thinking. I can make the index arrays easily enough with `np.tile` (or with `np.meshgrid` as you suggest). The part I don't see is how to do in a `numpy` setting, is what `accumarray` does in the above example. You can't input the output of `np.meshgrid` to `np.bincount` directly since `np.bincount` only takes 1D arrays. `np.ravel` will destroy the index information going into  `np.bincount` so that's no use. Could just do the loops explicitly in Cython...would people recommend that if array manipulation proves overly complicated? Thanks in any case for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way is to convert the 3 "indices" to a linear index and then apply `bincount`. Numpy's [`ravel_multi_index`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ravel_multi_index.html) is essentially the same as MATLAB's `sub2ind`. So the ported code could be something like:

```
shape = (Lmax+1, Lmax+1, maxvalue+1)
posvec = np.arange(1, Lmax+1)

ind_len  = np.tile(Lvec[:,None], [1, Lmax])
ind_pos  = np.tile(posvec,       [n,    1])
ind_val  = data
Y_copied = np.tile(Y[:,None],    [1, Lmax])

mask = posvec <= Lvec[:,None]  # fill-value independent
lin_idx = np.ravel_multi_index((ind_len[mask], ind_pos[mask], ind_val[mask]), shape)
Y_avg = np.bincount(lin_idx, weights=Y_copied[mask], minlength=np.prod(shape)) / n
Y_avg.shape = shape
```

This is assuming `data` has shape `(n, Lmax)`, `Lvec` is Numpy array, etc. You may need to adapt the code a little to get rid of off-by-one errors.

One could argue that the `tile` operations are not very efficient and not very "numpythonic". Something with [`broadcast_arrays`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_arrays.html) could be nice, but I think I prefer this way:

```
shape = (Lmax+1, Lmax+1, maxvalue+1)
posvec = np.arange(1, Lmax+1)

len_idx  = np.repeat(Lvec, Lvec)
pos_idx  = np.broadcast_to(posvec, data.shape)[mask]
val_idx  = data[mask]
Y_copied = np.repeat(Y, Lvec)

mask = posvec <= Lvec[:,None]  # fill-value independent
lin_idx = np.ravel_multi_index((len_idx, pos_idx, val_idx), shape)
Y_avg = np.bincount(lin_idx, weights=Y_copied, minlength=np.prod(shape)) / n
Y_avg.shape = shape
```

Note `broadcast_to` was added in Numpy 1.10.0.